# Unable to click button on popup confirmation in Testcafe

Tags: testing, automated-tests, click, selector, testcafe

I want to click Yes on confirmation button, here's the script.

```
.click(Selector('button').withAttribute('class', 'btn btn-default').withText('Yes'))
```

But I got an error: The element that matches the specified selector is not visible.

Here's the snippet code of the app
 [image: snippet code]

I tried `visible` in expected, like below

```
.expect(Selector('.btn.btn-default').withText('Yes').visible).ok()
.click(Selector('.btn.btn-default').withText('Yes'))
```

but got error:

> AssertionError: expected false to be truthy

Answer (score 2):

try

```
await t.click(Selector('.jconfirm-buttons).find('button').withText('Yes'))
```

Comment: still the same, I got error: The specified selector does not match any element in the DOM tree.

         | Selector('.jconfirm-buttons')
         |   .find('button')
       > |   .withText('Yes')

Comment: Check whether the element is inside an iframe